# Custom membership provider for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, membership, provider

I want to use NauckIT asp.net membership provider for Postgres.

I was playing with example and I managed to register/login/logout user. However, This membership provider also has role management, but i dont know how to use it.

My question is: Is it possible to use ASP.NET Configuration utility (the one you start from menu Project>ASP.NET Configuration) to create roles and users? How do I achieve this?

If this is not possible, Is there any other way to do this (besides inserting/update roles/users directly to Postgres DB - this is not much user friendly)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roles are managed by a [RoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx) in ASP.Net

I would imagine if it has a custom Membership provider, then it would also have a custom role provider as well. If this is the case, then you can certainly use the out of the box [Management Pages for ASP.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t32yf0a9.aspx) as it simply uses the Role and Membership providers that are already defined.

It would appear that [NauckIT does in fact have a role provider.](http://dev.nauck-it.de/wiki/1/Install)

Again, the management pages should work just fine if following the instructions in the link above.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I have tried 3 different custom membership providers for postgres and decided to use nauckit asp.net membership provider. Do you now how to make nauckit role management and managment pages for asp.net work together?